# position: fixed with margin: auto in IE9/10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I've made a sticky header for a responsive site where the header also is centered with `margin: 0 auto`. It works in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/IE8 but not in IE9+.

Minimal markup:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <header class="banner">
    </header>
</div>
```

And the style:

```
.banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In IE9+ the header is stuck to the left side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specifically add `width: 100%` to your element in question.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/970w09n8/)**

[image]

css

```
.banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
}
```

---

In-fact it works equally well in IE9

[image]

Comment: IE11 renders differently from 8,9 and 10. MS, literally changes the thing in almost every version.

Comment: You say that like it's a bad thing.

Comment: Well there you are... I actually don't have `width: 100%` in the code.