# CSS Header has wrong position in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, header

The header position of my website is always aligning to the left side in IE.
But it should be in the middle, in Chrome and Firefox its working without problems.

May i ask for your expertice for this?

Homepage:

CSS Code:

```
.header {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 950px;
  height: 141px;
  background: url(../img/bg_top.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 100; }
```

Comment: Try with `width: 950px` instead of max-width

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position: fixed with margin: auto in IE9/10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389321/position-fixed-with-margin-auto-in-ie9-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By margin auto and max-width fixed no need to give left and right .It will automatically placed in the center of the page.

So just remove left and right

```
  .header { 
    top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 950px;
    height: 141px;
    background: url(../img/bg_top.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 100; }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i removed left and right, and changed the "max-width" to "width", now its perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code for proper solution.

For header class you need to add below CSS

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and for navigation part, you need to update left side margin with below CSS.

```
.nav .ul .li {
    margin-left: 32px;
}
```